# using ember trying to set value in controller from route model hook yields error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller for this route that I have created and everything else in the controller seems to work great. I am trying to pass the meta value to a variable in the controller from the route and I get a console error:

```
Error: Property set failed: object in path "controller" could not be found or was destroyed.
```

this is the relevant snippet in my route:

```
 model(params){                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   let someVariable = this.store.query('somePath', params);                                                                                                                                       
   someVariable.then((results) => {                                                                                                                                                                                     
       this.set('controller.totalPages', results.get('meta.page_count'))                                                                                                                                                 
   });                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   return someVariable;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 }
```

in the console error the line with the issue is this one

```
this.set('controller.totalPages', results.get('meta.page_count'));
```

The other interesting snippet is when I sort a row on my data table and make the model request again my 'totalPages' variable finally shows up as expected(with the meta value), its on the initial page load that I dont see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `model` hook is executed, `controller` has not been set up yet. Check out the route lifecycle--the controller is available after `model` and `afterModel` etc. have not only returned but also the promises they return have resolved. You should move your logic into `setupController`.

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.query('somePath', params);
},

setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('totalPages', model.get('meta.page_count'));
    this._super(...arguments);
}
```

Or, you could skip the `setupController` and just put an alias in your controller:

```
totalPages: Ember.computed.alias('model.meta.page_count')
```

Comment: @torazburo thank you for the response. The solution passed the totalPages variable from the meta and I can see it however, my model data is no longer present on the page. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: this is the error btw "Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.
...'"